# 403 forbidden error, in Nginx configuration for Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, webserver

I'm configuring a Nginx site for Wordpress and I'm getting this error:

> 2014/11/21 16:39:24 [error] 38741#0: *2 directory index of
>   "/var/www/html/jurisprudencialaboral.dev/" is forbidden, client:
>   192.168.3.1, server: jurisprudencialaboral.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "jurisprudencialaboral.dev"

This are the permissions assigned to that directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 apache root 4096 Nov 21 16:28 jurisprudencialaboral.dev
```

And this is the `jurisprudencia.dev` server content file:

```
server {
       server_name jurisprudencialaboral.dev jurisprudencia jurisprudencialaboral;
       root /var/www/html/jurisprudencialaboral.dev;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/jurisprudencialaboral.dev$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/jurisprudencialaboral.dev/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/jurisprudencialaboral.dev/error.log;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
        # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }

        # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
        # Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
        # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all;
        }

        # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

 # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
               access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        # Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
        #include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
        #include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;
}
```

I get it from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx), what I'm doing wrong? Why the 403 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is pretty clear. You request URI `/` so nginx tries to list the docroot content but as `autoindex` directive default value is false thus this action is not allowed and nginx returns the adequate HTTP `403`.

You forgot to set the `index` directive to serve an index file.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, why errors are not logged in? I can see previous one but the new doesn't get logged. For example, right now site is not working and I'm suspect is something related to DB but I'm not clear at all since logs still empty, why?

Comment: @ReynierPM Which log are you speaking about ?

Comment: This one `error_log /var/log/nginx/jurisprudencialaboral.dev/error.log` that file contain only errors like this `2014/11/21 16:49:25 [error] 38741#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/html/jurisprudencialaboral.dev/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.3.1, server: jurisprudencialaboral.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "jurisprudencialaboral.dev"` but now I got a blank page and need to find what is causing that issue but with no errors how do I know?

Comment: @ReynierPM If you have no error in nginx.log then either nginx is not running or there's simply no error. Check what's happening on php-fpm side.

Comment: Hmm that's weird I'm working in another site under Symfony2 and it's running on top of Nginx and PHP-FPM so Nginx is already running, anyway what would I check in PHP-FPM side?

Comment: This file `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log` is empty :-\